# MySQL - alternative to running multiple (custom) functions?

Tags: mysql

I currently have two custom functions in a MySQL query:

`proper` converts any text to proper case format (john smith -> John Smith)

`HTML_Unencode` decodes HTML entities (BB `&#039;` T -> BB&T).

When I run both together it nearly *doubles* the query runtime. I need a solution that can be run from within the current query. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
proper(HTML_UnEncode(`order`.`shipping_city`)) AS `City`
FROM `order`
```

**Input**

```
Que&eacute;bec
```

**Output**

```
Québec
```

Answer (score 1):

How to perform the functions of both `proper` and `HTML_UnEncode` faster at query time? I don't know.

But - I strongly suggest *not* doing it at query time. You *insert a row once*, but *query it many times*. So pay the cost at insert time.

In other words - if you can - rather store `Québec` (and not `Qu&eacute;bec`) into the table. Then your query is both simpler and much faster

```
SELECT
  `order`.`shipping_city` AS `City`
FROM `order`
```

Comment: The database receives customer order input, so if they use an accent mark on Québec it shows the HTML entity in the database.

Comment: @msklut - It is the code that stores the customer input in the order tables that needs to be "fixed". It should decode the Unicode entities as part of the input sanitising process.

Comment: That’s probably the best route to go.